# Python turtle UnboundLocalError

Tags: python, debugging, runtime-error

I keep getting a UnboundLocalError when I try assigning turtle to turtle.Turtle() in a function. Why is it? Is the name used in turtle.py?

```
import turtle    
def make_turtle():  
    turtle = turtle.Turtle()
    return turtle  

eu = make_turtle()
```

---

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/usr/PycharmProjects/LearningToThinkLikeAComputerScientist/c4 - Functions/test.py", line 6, in <module>
    eu = make_turtle()
  File "/home/luis/PycharmProjects/LearningToThinkLikeAComputerScientist/c4 - Functions/test.py", line 3, in make_turtle
    turtle = turtle.Turtle()
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'turtle' referenced before assignment
```

Comment: _line 3, in make_turtle turtle = turtle.Turtle()_ This line is not in the code you posted.  Please post your real code.

Comment: Is this really the complete `make_turtle` function?

Comment: Tried this with Python 3.6.5 under win10 and it works without error.

Comment: The error message refers to a line not in your posted code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the import statement you assign the name turtle.

Then you assign to it in the function. If I have understood this correctly, the python parser first esttablishes thet the name `turtle` is assigned which makes it local. Then it processes the line `turtle = turtle.Turtle()` fron right to left. On discovering that you try to retrieve the value pointed to by `turtle` it is not assigned, you get an error.

Instead try another name:

```
import turtle

def make_turtle():  
    cat = turtle.Turtle()
    return cat  

eu = make_turtle()
```